# IDocumentFilter using a HashMap as a dictionary Menu , to validate on a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, validation, hashmap, jtextfield

I have a Hashmap filled with information from a table in Sybase , with this structure

-INDEX  -   CHARACTERS

----1----           1234567890

----2-----        abcdefg..

I'm tryng to set a new CustomJTextField extended from JtextField, so this control would have an atribute named MASK and i can set in this attribute the Mask number ,something like this:

```
 customtextField = new CustomTextField(20);
 customtextField.set_MASK(1);
```

i already have the customtextField working with some extra attributes ,
the behaviour of the mask atribute would not let the user write letter that are not contained in the table , so if the customtextField is set as MASK(1) , the user would only be able to write only Numbers

i need help using the DocumentFilter, or any suggestion , i need to get the dictionaries from a table from Database,(user requirement),

EDIT*

by recommendation im trying to get an example of a DocumentFilter that only let the use type characters contained in a Array ( createed from a HAshMap)

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to use a [Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) instead.

This would allow you to construct filters that would restrict what the user could actually type, rather then relying on post validation.

Check [here](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for some examples

**Updated**

This is surprisingly simple.  Using the examples I linked.  I'm sure you'll be able to adapt them to your needs.

[image]

```
public class TestDocumentFilter01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestDocumentFilter01();
    }

    public TestDocumentFilter01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(createField("1234567890"), gbc);
            add(createField("stackoverflow"), gbc);
            add(createField("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "), gbc);
        }

        protected JTextField createField(String mask) {
            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            MaskFilter df = new MaskFilter();
            df.setMask(mask);
            ((AbstractDocument) (field.getDocument())).setDocumentFilter(df);
            return field;
        }

    }

    public class MaskFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        private char[] maskSet;
        private String mask;

        public void setMask(String mask) {
            this.mask = mask;
            this.maskSet = mask.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(this.maskSet);
        }

        public String getMask() {
            return mask;
        }

        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                                                         String string, AttributeSet attr)
                        throws BadLocationException {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(string);
            for (int i = buffer.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                char ch = buffer.charAt(i);
                if (Arrays.binarySearch(maskSet, ch) < 0) {
                    buffer.deleteCharAt(i);
                }
            }
            super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
        }

        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                                                int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (length > 0) {
                fb.remove(offset, length);
            }
            insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have ant example of a filter created from characters stored in a hashmap? , the table contains the characters allowed ,

Comment: @user2030181 Finally found some time :P